# Запись в объект data, vue.js

Tags: javascript, mvvm, инспекция-кода, vue.js

Хочу реализовать подобие регистрации и авторизации. Во время сабмита регистрационной формы, собираю данные из ее полей и добавляю их в массив объекта `data` при помощи `this.users.push()`. В результате всё добавляется, всё ок, но интересует насколько вообще это идеологически верно? Не нарушаются ли при этом какие-нибудь правила работы с MVVM или что-нибудь в таком духе?

P. S. также буду рад услышать советы по работе с формой, мне кажется, что тут тоже не всё правильно.

```js
console.clear();

const data = {
  regauth: {
    reg: true,
    activeClass: 'reg-auth__li--active',
    ordinaryClass: 'reg-auth__li'
  },
  users: [

  ],

};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: data,
  methods: {
    regSubmit: function(event) {
      this.users.push({
        'username': document.getElementById('username').value,
        'login': document.getElementById('login').value,
        'password': document.getElementById('password').value,
      });

      event.target.reset();

      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700&subset=cyrillic");
*:before,
*:after,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

main[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.reg-auth {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.reg-auth__options {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.reg-auth__li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: lightblue;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed lightblue;
  cursor: default;
}

.reg-auth__li--active {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
}

.input-field {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 300px;
}

.btn-ok {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-ok {
  background-color: #09a942;
  color: #fff;
}

.form__line {
  margin-bottom: .8em;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.form__line--submit {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<main role="main" id="app" v-cloak>
  <section class="reg-auth">
    <ul class="reg-auth__options">
      <li v-on:click="regauth.reg = true" v-bind:class="[ regauth.reg ? regauth.activeClass : '', regauth.ordinaryClass ]">Регистрация</li>
      <li v-on:click="regauth.reg = false" v-bind:class="[ !regauth.reg ? regauth.activeClass : '', regauth.ordinaryClass ]">Авторизация</li>
    </ul>
    <section class="registration" v-if="regauth.reg">
      <article class="registration__body">
        <form id="reg-form" class="form" @submit.prevent="regSubmit">
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="username">Имя</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="login">Логин</label>
            <input id="login" type="text" placeholder="Логин" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line form__line--submit">
            <button role="button" class="btn-ok">Зарегистрироваться</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section class="authentication" v-if="!regauth.reg">
      <article class="authentication__body">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="a-login">Логин</label>
            <input id="a-login" type="text" placeholder="Логин" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="a-pass">Пароль</label>
            <input id="a-pass" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line form__line--submit">
            <button role="button" class="btn-ok">Войти</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации есть раздел, посвященный работе с формами: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Вообще не рекомендуется напрямую работать с dom, а использовать реактивные свойства для получения значений из полей. В вашем случае можно было сделать так:

```js
console.clear();

const data = {
  regauth: {
    reg: true,
    activeClass: 'reg-auth__li--active',
    ordinaryClass: 'reg-auth__li',
    username: '',
    login: '',
    password: ''
  },
  users: [

  ],

};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: data,
  methods: {
    regSubmit: function(event) {
      this.users.push({
        'username': this.regauth.username,
        'login': this.regauth.login,
        'password': this.regauth.password,
      });

      this.regauth.username = ""
      this.regauth.login = ""
      this.regauth.password = ""

      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700&subset=cyrillic");
*:before,
*:after,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

main[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.reg-auth {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.reg-auth__options {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.reg-auth__li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: lightblue;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed lightblue;
  cursor: default;
}

.reg-auth__li--active {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
}

.input-field {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 300px;
}

.btn-ok {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-ok {
  background-color: #09a942;
  color: #fff;
}

.form__line {
  margin-bottom: .8em;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.form__line--submit {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<main role="main" id="app" v-cloak>
  <section class="reg-auth">
    <ul class="reg-auth__options">
      <li v-on:click="regauth.reg = true" v-bind:class="[ regauth.reg ? regauth.activeClass : '', regauth.ordinaryClass ]">Регистрация</li>
      <li v-on:click="regauth.reg = false" v-bind:class="[ !regauth.reg ? regauth.activeClass : '', regauth.ordinaryClass ]">Авторизация</li>
    </ul>
    <section class="registration" v-if="regauth.reg">
      <article class="registration__body">
        <form id="reg-form" class="form" @submit.prevent="regSubmit">
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="username">Имя</label>
            <input v-model="regauth.username" type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="login">Логин</label>
            <input v-model="regauth.login" type="text" placeholder="Логин" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
            <input v-model="regauth.password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line form__line--submit">
            <button role="button" class="btn-ok">Зарегистрироваться</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section class="authentication" v-if="!regauth.reg">
      <article class="authentication__body">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="a-login">Логин</label>
            <input id="a-login" type="text" placeholder="Логин" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line">
            <label for="a-pass">Пароль</label>
            <input id="a-pass" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="input-field" />
          </div>
          <div class="form__line form__line--submit">
            <button role="button" class="btn-ok">Войти</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

Также, учитывая, что это учебный пример и пользователи должны сохранятся в localStorage, имеет смысл инкапсулировать взаимодействие с ним, создав отдельный объект с минимальным набором функций типа чтения, записи элемента/элементов.

Comment: По работе с формой понял, так и сделаю. Что касается прямого пуша в массив внутри `data` — это норм?

Comment: Не совсем ясно, то вы планируете дальше с этим делать и что это за массив пользователей. Обычно данные регистрации отправляются на сервер и далее сервер решает, можно вам работать дальше или есть какие-то проблемы.

Comment: Это учебный пример реализации регистрации и логина, сервера тут не будет, только localStorage. На клиенте хранятся данные о пользователях, при логине введенные данные сверяются с имеющимися в объекте `data` и затем пользователя либо пускает дальше, либо нет.

Comment: В вашем варианте наверное стоит сохранять регистрируемых пользователей сразу в localStorage. А при загрузке страницы смотреть в ls и если есть пользователи, то добавить их в массив. На самом деле, все зависит от того насколько далеко вы готовы зайти в вашем примере) Если кроме формы регистрации будет что-то еще, то имеет смысл выделить ее в отдельный компонент.

Comment: Еще по поводу ls - инкапсулируйте взаимодействие с ним, создав отдельный объект с минимальным набором функций типа чтения элемента/элементов, записи элемента.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии, вынесите их пожалуйста в свой ответ, может кому-то еще пригодятся :-)